# Is it possible to breakdown a numpy array to run through 1 different value in every iteration?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

So, I have an excel spreadsheet which I want my programme to be able to access and get data from.

To do this I installed pandas and have managed to *import* the spreadsheet into the code.

```
Satellites_Path = (r'C:\Users\camer\Documents\Satellite_info.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(Satellites_Path, engine='openpyxl')
```

So this all works.

The problem is that what I want it to do is to grab a piece of data, say the distance between 2 things, and run this number through a loop. I then want it to go one down in the excel spreadsheet and do this again for the new number until there it finishes the column and then I want it to end.

The data file reads as:

```
   Number ObjectName  DistanceFromEarth(km)  Radius(km)  Mass(10^24kg)
0       0      Earth                    0.0      6378.1        5.97240
1       1       Moon               384400.0      1783.1        0.07346
```

I put the 'Number' in as I thought that I could do a loop of whilst Number is < a limit then run through these numbers but I have found that the datafile doesn't work as an array or integer so that doesn't work.
Since then, I have tried to put it into an integer by turning it into a NumPy array:

```
N = df.loc[:,'Number']
D = np.array(df.loc[:,'DistanceFromEarth(km)'])
R = np.array(df.loc[:,'Radius(km)'])
```

However, the arrays are still problematic. I have tried to split them up like:

```
a = (np.array(N))
print(a)
newa = np.array_split(a,3)
```

and this sort of now works but as a test, I made this little bit and it repeats infinitely:

```
while True:
    if (newa[0]) < 1:
        print(newa)
```

If 1 is made a 0, it prints once and then stops. I just want it to run a couple of times.

What I am getting at is, is it possible to read this file, grab a number from it and run through calculations using it, and then repeat that for the next satellite in the list? The reason I thought to do it this way is that I am going to make quite a long list. I already have a working simulation of local planets in the solar system but I wanted to add more bodies and doing it in the way that I was would make it extremely long to write, very dense and introduce more problems.
Reading from a file from excel would make my life a lot easier and make it more future-proof but I don't know if it's possible and I can't see anywhere online that is similar.

Comment: What would your desired output look like?

Comment: @BeRT2me preferably would just show a 0 then a 1 as if it had gone through and printed the 0 and then gone through and printed the 1. This would show me that it had gone through the first row and done everything I'll want it to do and then gone through the 2nd row. Should mean that I can do the same with the actual data rather than what is mostly a test column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas are absolutely a good choice here, but lack of knowledge of how to use them appears to be holding you back.

Here's a couple of examples that may be applicable to your situation:

1. Simple row by row calculations to make a new column:

```py
df['Diameter(km)'] = df['Radius(km)']*2
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
   Number ObjectName  DistanceFromEarth(km)  Radius(km)  Mass(10^24kg)  Diameter(km)
0       0      Earth                    0.0      6378.1        5.97240       12756.2
1       1       Moon               384400.0      1783.1        0.07346        3566.2
```

2. Running each row through a function:

```py
def do_stuff(row):
    print(f"Number: {row['Number']}", f"Object Name: {row['ObjectName']}")

df.apply(do_stuff, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Number: 0 Object Name: Earth
Number: 1 Object Name: Moon
```

Comment: Yes, I am pretty new to coding and I get stuck pretty quickly when finding new stuff. However, although helpful, it doesn't seem that what you have put here would take one value at a time. What I want it to do is to grab a value, from say radius, and do calculations with that, put through a result and then grab the next value down in radius. The problem with this is that I can't get it to deliver one value at a time. It just prints the whole array, or the ones that I specify. However the point of trying to put it into a datafile was to reduce the specification required for each step.

Comment: The second example does exactly this. It takes a single row at a time, from which you can take a single value, *do whatever you want with it, including the example of printing here* and then moves on to the next line.

Comment: If you wanted to apply the function only to rows where `ObjectName` was 'Earth', then you'd change it to something like: `df[df['ObjectName'] == 'Earth'].apply(do_stuff, axis=1)`

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll have a play with that tomorrow. Do you have anywhere you'd recommend I look for more resources on pandas?

Comment: Besides just going to the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html), even something like the [w3shools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/pandas/default.asp) Would be an okay place to start~